# mt19937 and uniform_real_distribution

Tags: c++, boost, prng, mersenne-twister

I am trying to find an efficient way to implement a uniform(0,1) distribution. Since I have to generate a very large number of samples, I chose mt19937 as engine. I am using the version from the boost library. My question is: what is the difference between using the output of the engine itself vs using uniform_real_distribution?

**Option #1**

```
std::random_device rd;
boost::mt19937 gen(rd());
boost::random::uniform_real_distribution<double> urand(0, 1);

for ( int i = 0; i < 1E8; i++ ) {
    u = urand(gen);
}
```

**Option #2**

```
std::random_device rd;
boost::mt19937 gen(rd());

for ( int i = 0; i < 1E8; i++ ) {
    u = (double) gen()/gen.max();
}
```

From my tests, Option #2 is considerably better than Option #1 in terms of runtime. Is there any reason I should pick Option #1 over Option #2?

Comment: Without looking at the implementation itself it's impossible to know for sure, but I'd assume that `uniform_real_distribution` uses more bits to ensure that every possible floating point result in the range can be returned. Option #2 will have holes that are `1/gen.max()` apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the underlying implementation of `urand()`, but using the result of a division is likely to produce bias in the low-order bits as a quantisation effect.  If `gen.max()` isn't large then "low-order bits" may be very many or most of the bits of the result.

The performance disparity may come from producing properly distributed random numbers.  If `double` is overly precise for your needs then perhaps using `float` might allow it to run more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: what is the difference between using the output of the engine itself vs using uniform_real_distribution?

In your first option `urand()` has the range `[0,1)`, whereas your second option has the range `[0,1]` (if `boost::mt19937::min() == 0`, which usually holds).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice the difference in range. It seems then that the second option is better both in terms of performance and quality of the random number generator?