# Mersenne Twister & receiving Semantic Issue in the algorithm.h

Tags: c++, random, mersenne-twister

I’m very new to programming, and hope this question isn't burdensome. As a part of a video tutorial series I am using via YouTube that uses a series of challenges for students to use the portions of the language up to that point to solve a predefined problem. In this case, its making a simple Humans Vs Skeleton “1D Combat Simulator” (LINK: https://youtu.be/TH7plF4UT_E?list=PLSPw4ASQYyynKPY0I-QFHK0iJTjnvNUys)

The tutor, Ben, originally uses default_random_engine, but in his annoyed note of the video states that this is a bad implementation and mt19937 is a better choice. (LINK: https://youtu.be/JGwSEbnJGR0?list=PLSPw4ASQYyynKPY0I-QFHK0iJTjnvNUys&t=138).

I have searched through Stack Overflow as well as cplusplus.com, and other sites, etc.

I could not find helpful hints in either of these. Most Mersenne Twister questions seemed to be issues with it’s use, not with problems in any header or library files.
: [Issues with c++ 11 mersenne_twister_engine class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20527043/issues-with-c-11-mersenne-twister-engine-class)
: [How to run Mersenne Twister inside a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759891/how-to-run-mersenne-twister-inside-a-function)
: [mt19937 and uniform_real_distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372137/mt19937-and-uniform-real-distribution)
: [Why do I get the same sequence for every run with std::random_device with mingw gcc4.8.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880654/why-do-i-get-the-same-sequence-for-every-run-with-stdrandom-device-with-mingw)

I decided to go the rout of mt19937 for a more accurate random generation with more entropy, as I understand it. It may be overkill for the small project I am working on, and am open to better solutions.

I often become bored with most C++ tutorials (videos or books) as they teach the syntax & vocabulary, but rarely teach problem solving with the language. So, I skip around and toy with things, even when I don’t understand them, so that I can try to understand them better. My understanding of functions, in terms of their anatomy and best use, is weak. The same goes with classes. Nonetheless, I have implemented met19937 into a function so I could create various polyhedral die simulations. (d4, d6, d8, d10).

My source code doesn’t have any errors, however, the algorithm.h file has two errors of the same type, as follows.

***Type ‘std::__1::mersenne_twister_engine (long)’ cannot be used prior to ‘::’ because it has no members***

When I go into the algorithm.h file (as if I knew what I were doing), these are the lines of code that the errors are found in.

```
private:
typedef typename _Engine::result_type _Engine_result_type;
typedef typename conditional
    <
```

and

```
tatic _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR const _Working_result_type _Rp = _Engine::max() - _Engine::min()
                                                  + _Working_result_type(1);
```

(respectively on lines 2844 & 2866 of the file.)

This is my source code, I have commented out a lot of items, as I am trying to get one thing working before toying around with the rest:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
//#include <chrono>
//#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

/*
  // Simple Attack and Defense Attributes.
 int Agility = 40;
 int Attack =52;

 int MyAgility = 45;
 int MyAttack = 64;
*/

//Globals
mt19937 randomGenerator(time_t);
//default_random_engine randomGenerator(time_t);

//Function Protypes
void d4();
void d6();
void d8();
void d10();
void SuccessCheck();


int main()
{

    //Variables
    int MyWarriors;
    //int WarriorsAvailable = NULL;
    //int Skeletons = NULL;
    //int CharacterCount;

    /*
    int Attack;
    int Defense;
    int AxeDMG = 1;
    int SwordDMG = 2;
    int ShieldDEF = 1;

    //String Variables
    //Too Many Soldiers Requested
    char str1[150] = "I'm sorry Sire, we just don't have that many troops available.";
    char str2[150] = "No sir! We just can't manage that.";
    char str3[150] = "Oh! Our woes would not be so terrible, should we only have that many in our guard.";
    char str4[150] = "Have you been listening to my counsel? We just can't raise an army that size in such a short time.";
    char str5[150] = "Very well Sir, I suppose we'll perish until you can't give me a real answer.";

    //A Valid Amount of Soldiers Requested
    char str6[150] = "Great! I'll send them through the gates immediately!";
    char str7[150] = "YES! Through the forest, they'll ut down our foes!";
    char str8[150] = "By the Lord Almighty, they shall be vanquished!";
    char str9[150] = "They won't stand a chance!";
    char str10[150] = "No man or beast will rise against you again!";

    //Maybe Not Enough Soldiers Requested
    char str11[150] = "You may need a tad more men, Sire.";
    char str12[150] = "Perhaps, you'd like to join your men, just in case they need help?";
    char str13[150] = "I think we have a few more men you could send, Sire.";
    char str14[150] = "Oh yea, you'll have them quaking in their boots. Much like kittens and babies would. Perhaps you could spare a few more?";
    char str15[150] = "You can't say that I didn't warn you. Maybe send a few more men.";
    */


    //Random number of Skeletons!
    uniform_int_distribution<int> Skeletons (1, 3000);

    //Random number of Skeletons!
    uniform_int_distribution<int> WarriorsAvailable (1, 3000);

    //Invalid MySoldier Selection
    uniform_int_distribution<int> TooManySoldiers (1, 5);

    //Random number of Skeletons!
    uniform_int_distribution<int> RightNumSoldiers (6, 10);

    //Random number of Skeletons!
    uniform_int_distribution<int> ATadMoreSoldiers (11, 15);

    cout << "Sire! There are " << Skeletons(randomGenerator) << " marching toward the castle!" << endl << "We should send out our troops!" << endl;
    cout << "Our registry indicates that we have " << WarriorsAvailable << " who are combat ready!";
    cout << "How many warriors do wich to send out to battle?" << endl;
    cin >> MyWarriors;


    /*
    do {
        <#statements#>
    } while (<#condition#>); (MyWarriors > WarriorsAvailable)
        cout <<  << endl << "How many warriors woudl you like to send in to combat?";


    cout << "Yes, Sire! I will rally " << MyWarriors << " to do battle with our enemy, at once!" << endl << endl;


    */

    return 0;

}


//Dice Functions: Many of these functions cam from a Stack Overflow answer I found weeks prior to joining
void d4(){//function prints a randomly generated number
    //mt19937 randomGenerator(time_t);
    //auto seed = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    uniform_int_distribution<int> d4Die (1, 4);
    int d4Roll = d4Die(randomGenerator); //the generated number is then set equal to an integer for functionality
    cout << d4Roll; //finally, the integer is printed to the screen
}


void d6(){//function prints a randomly generated number
    //mt19937 randomGenerator(time_t);
    uniform_int_distribution<int> d6Die (1, 6);
    int d6Roll = d6Die(randomGenerator); //the generated number is then set equal to an integer for functionality
    cout << d6Roll; //finally, the integer is printed to the screen
}

void d8(){//function prints a randomly generated number
    //mt19937 randomGenerator(time_t);
    uniform_int_distribution<int> d8Die (1, 8);
//the generated number is then set equal to an integer for functionality
    int d8Roll = d8Die(randomGenerator);
    cout << d8Roll; //finally, the integer is printed to the screen
}

void d10(){//function prints a randomly generated number
    //mt19937 randomGenerator(time_t);
    uniform_int_distribution<int> d10Die (1, 10);
    //the generated number is then set  equal to an integer for functionality
    int d10Roll = d10Die(randomGenerator); 
    cout << d10Roll; //finally, the integer is printed to the screen
}

void SuccessCheck(){//function prints a randomly generated number
    //mt19937 randomGenerator(time_t);
     //Success Check based on a percentile roll of (2d10) yielding a 1 - 100%
    uniform_int_distribution<int> SCDie (1, 100);
    //the generated number is then set equal to an integer for functionality
    int SCRoll = SCDie(randomGenerator); 
    cout << SCRoll; //finally, the integer is printed to the screen

}

//Combat Skill Modifier
uniform_int_distribution<int> CmbSklMod (1, 3);

//uniform_real_distribution<float> SucessCheck(0.0f, 1.0f);
```

Comment: `mt19937 randomGenerator(time_t);` is a function declaration and I guess it may not be what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that

```
mt19937 randomGenerator(time_t);
```

Is not creating a random numnber generator.  It declares a function named `randomGenerator` that takes a `time_t` and returns a `mt19937`.

What you need to do is use something like

```
std::random_device rd
std::mt19937 randomGenerator{rd()};
```

This will create the PRNG and seed it with the initial value from `rd`.  If you want a better seed then you can use

```
std::random_device rd;
std::seed_seq seed{rd(), rd(), rd(), rd(), rd(), rd(), rd(), rd()};
std::mt19937 randomGenerator(seed);
```

The above technique comes from [bames53](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365496/bames53) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15509942/4342498)

Comment: I'll work on these possible solutions and get back to everyone with a comment. I really appreciate the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Nathan! This actually helped quite a bit. Once I entered the first option I received new errors, below will be an explanation of the errors and how I resolved them. Of course I suspect more seasoned programmers would see it as obvious. :P

**Error**
*use of class template uniform_int_distribution requires template arguments*

**Resolved with Code:**

```
uniform_int_distribution<int> Skeletons (randomGenerator);
```

**Error**

*no matching constructor for initialization of uniform_int_distribution
 use of undeclared identifier Skeletons*

**Resolved with Code:**

```
uniform_int_distribution<int> Skeletons (1, 3000);
```

*Additional help came from:* [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

**Final Working Code Snippets:**

```
std::random_device rd;
std::seed_seq seed{rd(), rd(), rd(), rd(), rd(), rd(), rd(), rd()};
std::mt19937 randomGenerator(seed);
```

and in use

```
//Random number of Skeletons!
uniform_int_distribution<int> Skeletons (1, 3000);

//Random number of Available Warriors!
uniform_int_distribution<int> WarriorsAvailable (1, 3000);

//Invalid MySoldier Selection
uniform_int_distribution<int> TooManySoldiers (1, 5);

//Random number of Skeletons!
uniform_int_distribution<int> RightNumSoldiers (6, 10);

//Random number of Skeletons!
uniform_int_distribution<int> ATadMoreSoldiers (11, 15);
```

============= The Reliability of the Messner-Twister =====================
This is why the rd() is use so much in the above code.

Are there better, more accurate methods? Here's a 'warning' about the
Messner-Twister and how it is predictable until it is seeded better.

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509270/does-stdmt19937-require-warmup/15509942#15509942)

====================== Indirectly related =================================

From the above posted code from my question, I thought I would link where my Dice Functions came from.

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/138382/

void d4(){//function prints a randomly generated number
    uniform_int_distribution d4Die (1, 4);
    int d4Roll = d4Die(randomGenerator); //the generated number is then set equal to an integer for functionality
    cout << d4Roll; //finally, the integer is printed to the screen
}

======================= Footnotes =====================================

Thank you both for your help. I hope this answer can help others who are new to the language overcome this or similar issues for PRGN. Whether it is for a combat system or Role Playing Game (RPG), may it be useful.

Comment: **URL's to other implementations for Die simulations**
*(for those who stumble across this answer)*

Phill's Projects
http://philipwashy.blogspot.com/2016/06/ive-been-working-on-building-video-game.html

Red Blob Games:
http://www.redblobgames.com/articles/probability/damage-rolls.html

https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3551.pdf